# Unity Animator Default Layer State Freezes on First Frame

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I animated a knife being drawn and an Idle state, however no matter what I do they will not animate in game. It instead freezes on the first frame.
Thi is what the animator window looks like when it is running:
[image: When running]

The Animation: 
[image: The Animation Tab]

And in the inspector:

[image: In the Inspector Tab]

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar problem and it came down to the transitions in the animation controller having "Can Transition to Self" checked, and unchecking it allowed the animation to run.

Comment: While it probably doesn't fix the topic starter's issue, it fixed mine, so thanks a lot. The issue which is fixed by your solution might easily occur when there is a transition from "Any State", which in pair with this checkbox makes the transition happen to the same state infinitely.

Comment: Additionally, if you have the interruption source on the transition as "Next State" it'll freeze as well.